# Правильно писать "ставни в домах" или "ставни на домах"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, морфология, предлоги, словосочетания

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно писать "ставни в домах" или "ставни на домах"?

Comment: Писать надо "ставни на окнах", на домах-то ставни откуда?

Comment: Полное предложение приведите.

Comment: "когда наступает ночь, в домах закрывают ставни"

Comment: На мой взгляд, вполне нормально. Здесь выражение "в домах" подразумевает "люди, живущие в домах, закрывают ставни изнутри". При этом совершенно неправильно звучит: *"Я шел вдоль деревни и видел ставни в домах".